# How to create a log-out link inside another php page

Tags: php, html, authentication, aptana, logout

I want to include a link to my logout.php which includes code to destroy the session inside my php on this page how would I do this?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo 'Welcome';
        "<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>";
    } else {
        include 'loginform.php';
        echo 'Please Log In';
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's not particularly clear whether your session destroy code exists and it's just the link you're after, or if it's the whole shebang.

Comment: im just after the code to link it too my logout.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code, if the SESSION is empty:

```
<?
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo 'Please Log In';
    include 'loginform.php';
}else{
echo 'Welcome';
?>
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you use any $_SESSION variable, you have to call `session_start()`
The logout should first open the session by calling `session_start()`, then destroy it by calling `session_destroy`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't currently telling PHP to display the link to the logout page. It either needs to be included in the `echo` or outputted elsewhere. For example;

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))   {
    echo 'Welcome';
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
}
else {
    include 'loginform.php';
    echo 'Please Log In';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your logout.php put this code ,

```
<?php
 session_start();
 session_destroy();
 ?>
```

Comment: Which session this will destroy. First you have to call session_start, or there is no session to be destroyed.

Comment: my  logout.php already contains <?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:./Login.php')
?>
i just need to know how to create a link to that inside the tag ive originally posted

Comment: `<?php echo '<a href="logout.php">logout</a>' ?>` like this , i guess.